# What are the Shallow water equations in differential form and cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, coordinate-systems

I am ignoring bed height or any other extra terms. The version of SWE when written in cartesian is:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
h  \\
hu  \\
hv  \\
\end{pmatrix}_t  + 
\begin{pmatrix}
hu  \\
hu^2 + \frac{g}{2} h^2  \\
huv  \\
\end{pmatrix}_x  +\begin{pmatrix}
hv  \\
huv \\
hv^2 + \frac{g}{2} h^2   \\
\end{pmatrix}_y = 0
$$

First what is it in differential form? I think it is:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}h + \nabla \cdot (hv) = 0 \quad 
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}h + \nabla \cdot (hvv) = - \nabla \frac{h^2}{2} g  $$
The pressure term at the end is what I'm really uncertain about. I think it must be a gradient as it comes from the pressure gradient term and it seems to fit but I couldn't derive it from Euler. **What is it supposed to be?**

Finally to write SWE in cylindrical coordinates, if I had the correct differential form can I just use the del in cylindrical coordinates formulas and $v = (u_r, u_\theta)$ and plug these in to get it? **And can I expect it to be harder to solve in cylindrical as I seem to get forcing terms?**

Comment: Cross-posted on math: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3324413/87420

Comment: I'm assuming that, in your model, the fluid density is constant, otherwise you're missing factors of $\rho$ throughout.

Comment: @KyleKanos That's correct, I am modeling an incompressible fluid.